# How should I keep track of the start time of a new clock object?

Tags: python, clock, accumulator, data-members

I'm writing a clock object that can be used to time events in a program and then report on its various times, such as the time it has been running for, its start and stop times and so on. I've written also a *clocks* object that keeps track of the various instances of clocks used throughout a program and summarises the details of all of the clocks in a printout.

I've got the clock object working, but I'm having difficulty seeing how to keep track of its start time in my current implementation. This is because it resets its internal record of the start time in order to add time to its internal accumulator correctly. I would appreciate any guidance on getting the thing working.

The code is below. I've included the code on the *clocks* object and so on so that it is clear what I am trying to achieve and so that suggested solutions do not remove key functionality (I've made it as minimal as I know how otherwise).

```
from __future__ import division
import os
import time
import uuid as uuid
import datetime

def main():

    global clocks
    clocks = Clocks()

    print("create clock alpha")
    alpha = Clock(name = "alpha")
    print("clock alpha start time: {time}".format(time = alpha.startTime()))
    print("sleep 2 seconds")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("clock alpha current time (s): {time}".format(time = alpha.time()))

    print

    print("create clock beta")
    beta = Clock(name = "beta")
    print("clock beta start time: {time}".format(time = beta.startTime()))
    print("sleep 2 seconds")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("clock beta current time (s): {time}".format(time = beta.time()))
    print("stop clock beta")
    beta.stop()
    print("clock beta start time: {time}".format(time = beta.startTime()))
    print("clock beta stop time: {time}".format(time = beta.stopTime()))
    print("sleep 2 seconds")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("clock beta current time (s): {time}".format(time = beta.time()))

    print

    print("create two gamma clocks")
    gamma1 = Clock(name = "gamma")
    gamma1 = Clock(name = "gamma")
    print("sleep 2 seconds")
    time.sleep(2)

    print

    print("create two unnamed clocks")
    delta = Clock()
    epsilon = Clock()
    print("sleep 2 seconds")
    time.sleep(2)

    print

    print("clocks full printout:\n")
    clocks.printout(style = "full")

    print("clocks statistics printout:\n")
    clocks.printout()

class Clock(object):

    def __init__(
        self,
        name             = None,
        start            = True
        ):
        self._name       = name
        self._start      = start # Boolean start clock on instantiation
        self._updateTime = None # internal
        # If no name is specified, generate a unique one.
        if self._name is None:
            self._name = UID()
        # If a global clock list is detected, add a clock instance to it.
        if "clocks" in globals():
            clocks.add(self)
        self.reset()
        if self._start:
            self.start()

    def start(self):
        self._startTime  = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    def stop(self):
        self._updateTime = None
        self._startTime  = None
        self._stopTime   = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    # Update the clock accumulator.
    def update(self):
        if self._updateTime:        
            self.accumulator += (
                datetime.datetime.utcnow() - self._updateTime
            )
        else:
            self.accumulator += (
                datetime.datetime.utcnow() - self._startTime
            )
        self._updateTime  = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    def reset(self):
        self.accumulator  = datetime.timedelta(0)
        self._startTime   = None

    # If the clock has a start time, add the difference between now and the
    # start time to the accumulator and return the accumulation. If the clock
    # does not have a start time, return the accumulation.
    def elapsed(self):
        if self._startTime:
            self.update()
        return(self.accumulator)

    def name(
        self
        ):
        return(self._name)

    def time(self):
        return(self.elapsed().total_seconds())

    def startTime(self):
        if self._startTime:
            return(style_datetime_object(datetimeObject = self._startTime))
        else:
            return("none")

    def stopTime(self):
        if self._stopTime:
            return(style_datetime_object(datetimeObject = self._stopTime))
        else:
            return("none")

class Clocks(object):

    def __init__(
        self
        ):
        self._listOfClocks = []
        self._defaultReportStyle = "statistics"

    def add(
        self,
        clock
        ):
        self._listOfClocks.append(clock)

    def report(
        self,
        style = None
        ):
        if style is None:
            style = self._defaultReportStyle
        if self._listOfClocks != []:
            if style == "statistics":
                # Create a dictionary of clock types with corresponding lists of
                # times for all instances.
                dictionaryOfClockTypes = {}
                # Get the names of all clocks and add them to the dictionary.
                for clock in self._listOfClocks:
                    dictionaryOfClockTypes[clock.name()] = []
                # Record the values of all clocks for their respective names in
                # the dictionary.
                for clock in self._listOfClocks:
                    dictionaryOfClockTypes[clock.name()].append(clock.time())
                # Create a report, calculating the average value for each clock
                # type.
                string = "clock type".ljust(39) + "mean time (s)"
                for name, values in dictionaryOfClockTypes.iteritems():
                    string += "\n" +\
                              str(name).ljust(39) + str(sum(values)/len(values))
                string += "\n"
            elif style == "full":
                # Create a report, listing the values of all clocks.
                string = "clock".ljust(39) + "time (s)"
                for clock in self._listOfClocks:
                    string += "\n" +\
                              str(clock.name()).ljust(39) + str(clock.time())
                string += "\n"
        else:
            string = "no clocks"
        return(string)

    def printout(
        self,
        style = None
        ):
        if style is None:
            style = self._defaultReportStyle
        print(self.report(style = style))

def UID():
    return(str(uuid.uuid4()))

def style_datetime_object(
    datetimeObject = None,
    style = "YYYY-MM-DDTHHMMSS"
    ):
    # filename safe
    if style == "YYYY-MM-DDTHHMMSSZ":
        return(datetimeObject.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%SZ'))
    # microseconds
    elif style == "YYYY-MM-DDTHHMMSSMMMMMMZ":
        return(datetimeObject.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S%fZ'))
    # elegant
    elif style == "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS UTC":
        return(datetimeObject.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%SZ'))
    # UNIX time in seconds with second fraction
    elif style == "UNIX time S.SSSSSS":
        return(
            (datetimeObject -\
            datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds()
        )
    # UNIX time in seconds rounded
    elif style == "UNIX time S":
        return(
            int((datetimeObject -\
            datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds())
        )
    # filename safe
    else:
        return(datetimeObject.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%SZ'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

An example printout on running is as follows:

```
create clock alpha
clock alpha start time: 2014-12-28T060943Z
sleep 2 seconds
clock alpha current time (s): 2.001554

create clock beta
clock beta start time: 2014-12-28T060945Z
sleep 2 seconds
clock beta current time (s): 2.001759
stop clock beta
clock beta start time: none
clock beta stop time: 2014-12-28T060947Z
sleep 2 seconds
clock beta current time (s): 2.001759

create two gamma clocks
sleep 2 seconds

create two unnamed clocks
sleep 2 seconds

clocks full printout:

clock                                  time (s)
alpha                                  10.01031
beta                                   2.001759
gamma                                  4.004501
gamma                                  4.004482
fdce3cc9-2178-4a72-99c5-22c77ad9cbbc   2.002209
d90d9263-ffaf-44f1-ace9-f8ddf5c78d87   2.002156

clocks statistics printout:

clock type                             mean time (s)
alpha                                  10.010368
beta                                   2.001759
d90d9263-ffaf-44f1-ace9-f8ddf5c78d87   2.00219
gamma                                  4.004532
fdce3cc9-2178-4a72-99c5-22c77ad9cbbc   2.002244
```

The key line that illustrates the problem is `clock beta start time: none`. The clock "beta" should be reporting `2014-12-28T060945Z` at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem (I asume, I didn't read through your entire mass of code) is in this block at the beginning:

```
print("create clock beta")
beta = Clock(name = "beta")
print("clock beta start time: {time}".format(time = beta.startTime()))
print("sleep 2 seconds")
time.sleep(2)
print("clock beta current time (s): {time}".format(time = beta.time()))
print("stop clock beta")
beta.stop()
print("clock beta start time: {time}".format(time = beta.stopTime())) # right here
print("clock beta stop time: {time}".format(time = beta.stopTime()))
print("sleep 2 seconds")
time.sleep(2)
print("clock beta current time (s): {time}".format(time = beta.time()))
```

You're printing *"clock beta start time:"*, but you're passing the results of `beta.stopTime()` to the string formatter, just as you're doing in the next line. Also, since you called `beta.stop()`, I'm not sure what you expect the last line to do, as theoretically `beta` was stopped 2 seconds ago.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look. The code in the ```main``` function is designed to illustrate the functionality of the clocks. The beta clock is created (and started) and its start time is printed out. There is a sleep for 2 seconds and the time elapsed is requested from the beta clock. Then, the beta clock is stopped and its functionality while stopped is demonstrated. It is supposed to retain its start time, its stop time and its accumulated time in this state. Then, there is another pause and a printout again from the beta clock in order to show that it *hasn't* changed because it is stopped.

Comment: You're right that there is a typo (well-spotted!) and I'll fix that now. I know that the problem still stands, though. The time returned by the beta clock at that point is ```None``` when it should be ```2014-12-28T060945Z```.